# как поменять сериализованные данные в теле ответа Django REST FrameWork?

Tags: python, django, rest

не совсем понимаю, как корректно сформировать вопрос, нужно добавить {"data":[]} в тело ответного словаря:

вот так сейчас:

```
    [
        {
            "id": 21314,
            "station": "Хорошевская",
            "line": "Не задано",
            "admarea": "Северный административный округ",
            "district": "Хорошёвский",
            "status": "действует",
            "s_id": "11"
        },
        {
            "id": 21315,
            "station": "Шелепиха",
            "line": "Не задано",
            "admarea": "Центральный административный округ",
            "district": "Пресненский",
            "status": "действует",
            "s_id": "12"
        },

#Нужно, что б стало так:

{data:
[
    {
        "id": 21314,
        "station": "Хорошевская",
        "line": "Не задано",
        "admarea": "Северный административный округ",
        "district": "Хорошёвский",
        "status": "действует",
        "s_id": "11"
    },
    {
        "id": 21315,
        "station": "Шелепиха",
        "line": "Не задано",
        "admarea": "Центральный административный округ",
        "district": "Пресненский",
        "status": "действует",
        "s_id": "12"
    },
]
}
```

#serializers.py >>

class MydataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
class Meta:
    model = Mydata
    fields = ('id', 'station', 'line', 'admarea', 'district', 'status', 's_id')
```

#views.py >>

class LimitMydataView(ListModelMixin, RetrieveAPIView):

```
queryset = Mydata.objects.all()
serializer_class = MydataSerializer

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    page = int(kwargs['page'])
    limit = int(kwargs['limit'])
    t2 = page*limit
    t1 = t2 - limit

    self.queryset = Mydata.objects.all()[t1:t2]
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Велосипедистое решение:

Вместо return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs) :

```
    piece = self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
    data = {}
    data['data'] = piece.data
    return Response(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

просто вложи свой сериализатор в новый, ну в туже DataSerializer.
Например

```
from rest_framework import serializers
import json


class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()


class DataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    data = MySerializer(many=True)


test = {"data": [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]}


print(json.dumps(DataSerializer(test).data))
```

out: {"data": [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]}